Does $\{\lfloor nx\rfloor : n\in\Bbb N\}\subset\{\lfloor ny\rfloor : n\in\Bbb N\}$ imply $x/y\in\Bbb N$?
For $x\in\mathbb (1, \infty)$, let $S_x:=\{\lfloor nx\rfloor: n\in\mathbb N\}$. Then $S_x$ have density $1/x$ over $\mathbb N$, which implies $S_x\ne S_y$ for $x\ne y$.
Of course $S_{mx}\subset S_x$ for $m\in \mathbb N_{>0}$. Can this happen otherwise? In other words, does $S_x\subset S_y$ imply $x/y \in\mathbb N$ for $x, y\in(1,\infty)$?

@JohnOmielan you're right, it was my mistake allowing  for $x$ to be $1$. I edited my statement.

Do you really intend strict subset, or is subset or equal to what you want?

@DanielV my intention was for allow equality, but I don't think it makes a difference, as $S_x = S_y\implies x = y$ and $x/y = 1$.

Poster has been clear and very responsive, this question deserves more than +1 upvote.

It can happen otherwise! These are Beatty sequences, and there's a theorem about them called Rayleigh's theorem or Beatty's theorem: if $x$ is irrational then $S_x$ and $S_{x/(x-1)}$ partition the positive integers. In particular, the OP's observation $S_{mx} \subset S_x$ implies the complementary relationship $S_{x/(x-1)} \subset S_{mx/(mx-1)}$; and it's straightforward to see that ratio between $x/(x-1)$ and $mx/(mx-1)$ cannot be an integer when $x$ is irrational.
When $x$ is rational, the two sets $S_x$ and $S_{x/(x-1)}$ still cover the positive integers, although they have a nonempty intersection. Still, it seems that the relationship $S_{x/(x-1)} \subset S_{mx/(mx-1)}$ holds even when $x$ is rational. Restricting $x$ to integer values for example, the set $S_{x/(x-1)}$ consists of all positive integers not congruent to $-1$ (mod $x$), which makes the relationship $S_{x/(x-1)} \subset S_{mx/(mx-1)}$ immediate to verify.
